# Convert array of floats to AVAudioPCMBuffer for speed recognition

Tags: ios, c, objective-c

I have an array of floats that is raw audio data from a 3rd party source. I would like to pass this through to a Speech Recognition request via `appendAudioPCMBuffer` but that accepts an `AVAudioPCMBuffer`. How could I convert my `NSMutableArray` to `AVAudioPCMBuffer`?

For reference, this is how the `buffer` variable gets created before its passed to this function. It is written in C.

```c
void CallNativePlugin( const float buffer[], int size ) {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:buffer[i]];
        [myArray addObject:number];
        [delegateObject recognizeSpeechFromBuffer:myArray ];
    }
}
```

Then the current code I have to take that `buffer` and pass is to the speech recognizer (objective-c):

```objectivec
-(void) recognizeSpeechFromBuffer: (NSMutableArray*) buffer {
    NSLog( @"Array length: %lu@", (unsigned long) buffer.count );
  
    recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = YES;
    recognitionTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:recognitionRequest.resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        BOOL isFinal = NO;
        if (result) {
            NSLog(@"RESULT:%@",result.bestTranscription.formattedString);
            isFinal = !result.isFinal;
        }
        if (error) {
            recognitionRequest = nil;
            recognitionTask = nil;
        }
    }];

    // Do something like [recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Objective-C is available in `CallNativePlugin`, you could rework it to create the `AVAudioPCMBuffer` there, assuming you know the audio sample rate and can adjust the delegate protocol.

```
// Assuming mono, sample rate ????
void CallNativePlugin( const float buffer[], int size ) {
    AVAudioFormat *fmt = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:/* ?? */ channels:1 interleaved:YES];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buf = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:fmt frameCapacity:size];
    memcpy(buf.floatChannelData[0], buffer, sizeof(float) * size);
    buf.frameLength = size;
    [delegateObject recognizeSpeechFromPCMBuffer:buf];
}
```

If that isn't possible you can create an `AVAudioPCMBuffer` in `-recognizeSpeechFromPCMBuffer:` similarly and assign the floats individually.